# OOP: Init method questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have two questions regarding the code below.

1. What is the difference between `self.a=self.test1()`  and `a=self.test1()`? One is class field and other one is object field?
2. Why cannot I define `result = self.a+self.b`? How to correct it?

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=self.test1()
        a=self.test1()
        self.b=Test.test2()
    
    result = self.a+self.b    
    def test1(self):
        a=100
        return a
    @classmethod
    def test2(cls):
        b=200
        return b

    @staticmethod
    def test3():
        print("Testing3 is calling ")
        c=500
        return c
```

Comment: If `test2` and `test3` have nothing to do with your question, they should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.a` is a property in this class. It will remain accessible throughout functions in the `Test()` class. `a = self.test1()`, however, goes away once `__init__(self)` finishes, because `a` is local to `__init__(self)`.

For `result = self.a + self.b`, I assume you want a variable called `result` calculated after `self.a` and `self.b` is defined? At that indentation level a statement like this is usually not allowed (I could be wrong), usually a declaration of a property of a class happens here.

Comment: A `class` statement can include arbitrary code in its body; it usually doesn't. An assignment is quite common: this just defines a class attribute named `result` (or would, if the right-hand side didn't raise a `NameError` over the undefined name `self`).

Comment: chepner: Make sense, thank you for the clarification

Comment: class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=self.test1()
        global b
        b=Test.test2()

    result = b

Comment: if i declare a global variable b, i can be access later ?

Comment: You definitely can. I assume `b` is outside of the `class Test()`?

Answer (score 2):

`self.a = self.test1()` creates an instance attribute named `a`. The attribute will be accessible from the object anywhere you have a reference to the object.

`a = self.test1()` defines a local variable named `a`. It will go out of scope once `__init__` returns.

`result = self.a + self.b` doesn't work because it is in a context where `self` is not defined. `self` is just the (conventional) name of the first parameter of an instance method. It's not defined in the namespace of the `class` statement itself.

Comment: ···class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=self.test1()
        b=Test.test2()

    result = b

Comment: Sure, but `result` will go out of scope when `__init__` returns, so there's little point in setting a local variable that doesn't get used later in the same function.